# Would casting Symbol inside a Portable Hole prevent it from being dispelled while moving?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The [*symbol*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol) spells states:

> If you choose an object, that object must remain in its place; if the object is moved more than 10 feet from where you cast this spell, the glyph is broken, and the spells end without being triggered.

This means if I cast it upon an object it cannot be moved more than 10ft from where it was cast without being dispelled.

If a cleric jumped into a [portable hole](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/portable-hole) and cast the spell on an object inside the hole, then climbed out and closed the hole.  Would moving the handkerchief count as moving the extra-dimensional hole it contains?

Therefore would *symbol* cast on the object be broken by moving the portable hole containing the object?

Answer (score 9):

The way to understand this is to notice that the extradimensional space inside of a portable hole is an entirely separate plane from the one in which the “handkerchief” of the hole-item exists. The hole-item merely gives access to this plane of existence by creating planar portal as an entrance when unfolded and placed on a surface. When the hole-item is folded up and moved, nothing happens to the items on the “inside” — they just sit there, in a lonely piece of the Multiverse, not moving at all no matter what happens to the hole-item.

So if anything cares about the contents of the portable hole moving, such as a *symbol* spell, moving the **entrance** item to the hole won't trigger it. The contents would need to actually be moved within the interior space to count as moving, or out of the hole entirely (which means moving to an entirely different *plane of existence*) to count as moving.

Comment: You beat me to the punch... this is exactly how I read that, unlike Bags of Holding and Haversacks this specifically states separate plane and access to it. So the space itself doesn't move just its access.

Comment: @Slagmoth Even the Haversack and Bag use separate planes; they say “extradimensional space”, which means a demiplane. It's not explicitly stated as part of their descriptions, but the section of the DMG about demiplanes makes it clear that all extradimensional spaces are demiplanes. (And that's as expected, since extradimensional spaces have always been that way in D&D.)

Comment: I agree that is how they have always been in the past but there is ambiguous verbiage between the 3 especially in the last paragraph although not really relevant to the question, the description of the Portable Hole just makes this sort of question much easier to answer even if the explicit part was meant to keep that old trick of walking through walls from happening in this edition :)